# Implication of switch closure on behaviour of circuit

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I have the following circuit, where: $$v_o(t) = -R(t)v_i(t)$$
$$v_i(t) = 1V$$
$$R(t) = (1 + 0.5cos(20\pi t))\theta (t)$$

And $$\theta(t)$$

is the Heaviside step function.

[image]

I'm asked to solve for v0 if the switch closes at t = 0s, which gives me:

$$v_o(t)=-1-0.5cos(20\pi t)$$

Next, I'm asked to solve for v0 if the switch closes at 50 ms. Now, I don't understand what effect this has and how I should mathematically model it.

What "happens" in the circuit between t = 0s and t = 50 ms if the switch is closed during that interval? How is that reflected in the equations that describe the circuit?

Comment: You've omitted \$\theta(t)\$ and \$v_i(t)\$ from you equation. Plug in values of t to find the responses at these two times, but it's not really clear what the question is.

Comment: Where does it say \$\theta(t)=1\$?

Comment: You should upload the original wording of the question - this is like trying to hit a moving target.

Comment: It doesn't read like a proper question. I give up.

Comment: Let's clean up this discussion then.

Comment: Are you sure the \$\theta(t)\$ term is supposed to be part of the resistor characteristic and not representing the effect of closing the switch?

Comment: @ThePhoton I think the term represents the effect of closing the switch.

Comment: Then it should not be included in the expression for R(t) if you want your equations to match your diagram.

Answer (score 1):

There are no energy-storage elements in your circuit, so assuming your op-amp is ideal there's no special effect from closing the switch.

Before the switch is closed, the output node is floating, so its voltage is undetermined.

After the switch is closed, the output is determined by the usual equation for an inverting op-amp amplifier.